# почему обрезается корневая страница HTML?

Tags: html, css

[image: скриншот результата]Задаётся фиксированная высота html-документу, но никаких стилей, влияющих на это, не задано. Из-за этого не задаются отступы блокам, стоящим ниже. В чём может быть проблема?

```css
.page {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: "TT Commons", sans-serif;
  background-color: #181414;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="page" lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Intercodes</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/logo.svg" type="image/svg">
  <link href="css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="body">
  <header class="header" id="header">
    <div class="header__logo logo">
      <a class="logo__link" href="index.html">
        <img class="logo__image" src="../img/logo-orange.svg" width="160" height="33" alt="Логотип студии">
      </a>
    </div>
    <nav class="header__menu menu">
      <button class="menu__button" id="menu__button" type="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="menu__list">
        <span class="menu__toggle"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="menu__list" id="menu__list">
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="wrapper__info">
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="js/menu__button.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.page {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: "TT Commons", sans-serif;
  background-color: #181414;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.body {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: не помогло, спасибо